# How to use specific conditions in dataFrame.loc in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe and i only want to select the rows if the 'code' is available in my set.
I am currently trying this:

```
country_codes = set(set(dle['Code']) & set(dgdp['Code']))
dgdp.loc[dgdp['Code'].str in country_codes]
```

or

```
dgdp.loc[dgdp['Code'] in country_codes]
```

On the second one I get the problem
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
and in the first one I get KeyError: False.

How can I get the info for the codes that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: dgdp.loc[dgdp['Code'].isin(country_codes)]